# Variable assignment has a type? What is this called?

Tags: c#, .net, variable-assignment

Saw something like this in a lazily loaded property getter:

```
public SomeClass SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _someVar ?? (_someVar = new SomeClass());
    }
}
```

Seems kind of obvious to me what is going on, I just managed to get by using C# for years now without noticing this would work:

```
int i = 0;
(i = 1).GetType();
```

I guess my primary question is, does this have some kind of special name I could use to search for more information about it/describe it to others? I guess I'm mostly curious if there are any gotchas associated with it (order of execution, etc, similar to what you'd have to think of when linking multiple null coalescing operators together), or if there are any other standard uses of this like the lazily loaded property getter seen above (even though I don't think it's particularly clean compared to the alternatives).

I'm almost embarrassed to post this since it seems like something that would be pretty hard to not have thought about/seen before, haha. Thanks in advance.

Comment: because of that fact you can write something like this: int x, y, z; x = y = z = 5;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a consequence of assignment being an expression in C#. From the [C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315.aspx):

> The result of a simple assignment expression is the value assigned to
>   the left operand. The result has the same type as the left operand and
>   is always classified as a value.

Comment: Lots of good answers, but this one explains it the clearest right from the source, so I'm marking it as the answer. Guess the fact that so many people responded means I was right to be embarrassed posting this question, hah.

Answer (score 2):

It's not variable assignment which has a type but it's the left hand side operand.

Any Expression which would be evaluated and returns something like a method call would be the same.

For more information consult these pages:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(programming)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science)#Expressions

Answer (score 1):

You have to look for the assignment operator, which evaluates as the newly set value. Basically in

```
(i = 1).GetType();
```

i is assigned the value 1 and the whole expression (i = 1) is evaluated as the integer 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's a line with two consequences or side-effects.  That is, it does two things: 1) it runs assignment; and 2) it uses the whole statement as the Right-Hand Side (RHS) of another statement.  I see this more frequently in C++ where `null` can be used as a BOOLEAN statement.

It's fine to use, but I prefer to be more expressive personally.  Having the two consequences, imo, makes it easier to miss something.  When I start reading a line with `return` I don't expect it to have a side-effect of assigning a variable as it does it.  Just my .02.

Answer (score 0):

An Assignment is an expression like any other, the value of the expression is the thing being assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

Long story in short:
Assignment operator returns value which has Type equal to the type of left-side variable.